# Scrollback to previous screens in session of screen in Putty

Tags: gnu-screen, putty

I use Putty to connect to my VPS and run `screen -r` to restore the Screen session.

Then I run a command in the Screen session. The command outputs a lot of content. When I scroll back to try to see the beginning of the content, I only see the content on the putty window before the `screen -r` command.

In other words, I can only see the last screen of the content that is output by the command running in the Screen session. Other part of the output is lost.

I use `Ctrl a:scrollback 2000`, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I see the whole output of the command running in a Screen session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the scrollback buffer of Screen. By default, this is done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>[</kbd> (or <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Now you can use <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys or <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> to scroll.

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit scrollback mode.

The reason is that the scrollback buffer of Putty (terminal emulator) and Screen (terminal multiplexer) are two different things.

Think of it as Screen adds an additional scrollback buffer inside your terminal emulator.